# Google Maps Javascript section causing text to become bold

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

Here is the code that affects it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.4893169, -2.1182648);
      var mapOptions = {
        center: latLng,
        zoom: 15,
        scrollwheel: false,
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);
      var image = 'images/map_blue.png';
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        icon: image
      });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
```

It's makes some of my text go bold, nothing shows up in Google inspect element for bold or font weight.. However if i remove said code ^ then it fixes itself..

This confuses me as I can't see how the two can be related.. I checked for missing characters in my html but its perfect (validated on sites too)..

Cheers Guys

Comment: Your java script is accurate. There must be another reason.

Comment: How could it affect it when I remove it then? I have other pages almost identical without this issue.. Also the page initially loads fine and about 0.2 seconds after load the font switches to bold.

Comment: Good question. Could you add your html etc to a fiddle so we can take a look?

Comment: In Chrome, inspect the bold element. Then open the "Computed" tab and search for font-weight. See where it is inherited from by clicking the triaggle on its left side. Inspector will tell you whether the style comes from CSS or it is, for example, inherited from a `strong` or `h1` parent tag.

Comment: The maps-API injects some CSS into the page when you load a map, maybe this CSS affects your document(hard to give a more detailed answer without seeing the HTML for the page)

Comment: Salaman A - I did that and there is nothing showing font weight etc :(

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/OMWlMWFZTmBSjM9aviJw?p=catalogue All my HTML

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem, reason is that page use font "Roboto" with font-weight: 300, but google maps load this font with weight 300,400,500,700 so "normal" eq 400, not 300 and text becomes bolder

Comment: Awesome, thanks - thats been puzzling me for a while!

Comment: how can i prevent this from happening?

Comment: font-weight: 300;

Comment: you are awesome!